# awk Removing Double Quotes from CSV File Quoted Strings separated by comma

Tags: bash, sed, csv, awk

I have a csv file I would like to remove any rouge `"` or `,` in it. The problem is all my fields look something like this `"***********","*********",` where `*` = can be any character including `,` and `"`. I need to remove any `,` or `"` that might appear between the delimiters `","` so my strings will remain in double quotes.

`"This, has a comma","This has "quotes"",",but what if this happens "too""`

ideally the output should be

`"This has a comma","This has quotes","but what if this happens too"`

I tried this, but it removed all my double quotes

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub("\"","", $i)}}1' input.csv > output.csv`

edit:
Tried aborruso solution on this sample input row.

```
"33333","23","01-07-31-0-000-026.001","   ","","55540","COUNTY ROAD","","","","COUNTY ROAD","","Y","","","VILLE","YY","33367","","","4.246","-22.331","3","X","6000      ","","134","","000003"," "," ","New New New 
 New","000000370","0000004111","0000002111","94111"," ","JOHN SMITH","BILL","E BILLY",""," ",", JANE DOE","DOE","BOB","","BILL E BILLY BOB",", JANE DOE JOHN DOE BABY DOE"," ","","313 MAIN BLVD","313","","","MAIN","BLVD","","","","NEW YORK","NY","48555","2335","Z005"," ","1234","0","0","12345","12345","0","12345","1234","    ","1234","","01","",""," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","0","","0","","","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","","","","","","","","","1","","","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","","","  ","       ","          ","       ","       ","01","      ","DISTRICT 9 THE MOVE","","       ","          ","DISNEY NETFLIX","","COME ADD 1/4 OF A CUP 1/4 OF A SPOON 13-T00Z-B32C; THE 524.01'(X)350'(Y)TO W R/W OF SO SI'LLY 987.7';WOULDN'T YOU SAY","24313317","Z",""
```

The output I get is like this

```
"(error)","(error)","01-07-31-0-000-026.001","   ","","(error)","COUNTY ROAD","","","","COUNTY ROAD","","Y","","","VILLE","YY","(error)
```

it's just a snippet but you get the idea.

Comment: Your `awk` is close :) take a look `echo '"This, has a comma","This has "quotes"",",but what if this happens "too""'|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""};{printf "\"";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/[,"]/,"",$i);printf $i;if (i!=NF){printf OFS};};};END{print "\""}'
"This has a comma","This has quotes","but what if this happens too"`

Comment: doesn't seem to work if I run into something like this ```,"string",""," ",", STRING","``` will out put an extra ```,``` in the end. This is what I tried ```awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""};{printf "\"";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/[,"]/,"",$i)}}1' bad.csv
```

Comment: This new input line isn't formatted as the example you posted, so it would need another type of filter. I think you got the idea about double and single quotes when running a short `awk` script in command line. To avoid that problem you can put the script into a file and call it with `awk -f file`.

Comment: Your start text, is not a CSV. To be a CSV it should be in this way https://gist.github.com/aborruso/b7c464f50e4bc18b89492dfce3910e11/revisions#diff-6eb5aa2af122281945d8d42cc285a04af319c927fec0b2e03ce47987c39985a2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) here (GNU sed) 4.7 :

```
sed 's/","/\x0/g;s/^"\|"$/\x1/g;s/[",]//g;s/\x0/","/g;s/\x1/"/g' input.csv
```

- Replace field separator `","` by NUL char (`\x0`)
- Replace `"` at the biginning and at the end by SOH char (`\x1`)
- Remove all `"` and `,`
- Restore field separator and `"`

Comment: I edited the original post. Please let me know if you are able to help in any way, thank you.

Comment: You don't tell what you get with my sed proposal.

Comment: It works for most cases, but one of the last rows gives an error. It says there's an extra column, but I can't find it yet. When I find it I'll update, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not awk, but I think it could be useful for you

If you use [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and run

```bsh
echo '"This, has a comma","This has ""quotes""",",but what if this happens ""too"""'| \
mlr --csv -N --quote-all cat then put -S 'for (k in $*){$[k]=gsub($[k],"(,|\")","")}'
```

you have

```
"This has a comma","This has quotes","but what if this happens too"
```

### Edit

You have inserted you input text. It's very strange, it's something like

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 | 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 | 112 | 113 | 114 | 115 | 116 | 117 | 118 | 119 | 120 | 121 | 122 | 123 | 124 | 125 | 126 | 127 | 128 | 129 | 130 | 131 | 132 | 133 | 134 | 135 | 136 | 137 | 138 | 139 | 140 | 141 | 142 | 143 | 144 | 145 | 146 | 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33333 | 23 | 01-07-31-0-000-026.001 |  |  | 55540 | COUNTY ROAD |  |  |  | COUNTY ROAD |  | Y |  |  | VILLE | YY | 33367 |  |  | 4.246 | -22.331 | 3 | X | 6000 |  | 134 |  | 000003 |  |  | New New New |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| New | 000000370 | 0000004111 | 0000002111 | 94111 |  | JOHN SMITH | BILL | E BILLY |  |  | , JANE DOE | DOE | BOB |  | BILL E BILLY BOB | , JANE DOE JOHN DOE BABY DOE |  |  | 313 MAIN BLVD | 313 |  |  | MAIN | BLVD |  |  |  | NEW YORK | NY | 48555 | 2335 | Z005 |  | 1234 | 0 | 0 | 12345 | 12345 | 0 | 12345 | 1234 |  | 1234 |  | 01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 01 |  | DISTRICT 9 THE MOVE |  |  |  | DISNEY NETFLIX |  | COME ADD 1/4 OF A CUP 1/4 OF A SPOON 13-T00Z-B32C; THE 524.01'(X)350'(Y)TO W R/W OF SO SI'LLY 987.7';WOULDN'T YOU SAY | 24313317 | Z |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Running the mlr command you have this CSV ouput

```
"33333","23","01-07-31-0-000-026.001","   ","","55540","COUNTY ROAD","","","","COUNTY ROAD","","Y","","","VILLE","YY","33367","","","4.246","-22.331","3","X","6000      ","","134","","000003"," "," ","New New New 
 New","000000370","0000004111","0000002111","94111"," ","JOHN SMITH","BILL","E BILLY",""," "," JANE DOE","DOE","BOB","","BILL E BILLY BOB"," JANE DOE JOHN DOE BABY DOE"," ","","313 MAIN BLVD","313","","","MAIN","BLVD","","","","NEW YORK","NY","48555","2335","Z005"," ","1234","0","0","12345","12345","0","12345","1234","    ","1234","","01","",""," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","0","","0","","","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","","","","","","","","","1","","","","","","0","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","","","  ","       ","          ","       ","       ","01","      ","DISTRICT 9 THE MOVE","","       ","          ","DISNEY NETFLIX","","COME ADD 1/4 OF A CUP 1/4 OF A SPOON 13-T00Z-B32C; THE 524.01'(X)350'(Y)TO W R/W OF SO SI'LLY 987.7';WOULDN'T YOU SAY","24313317","Z",""
```

Comment: Thank you I tried that and I'm getting "(error)","(error)" in some columns... any idea why that is? It looks like it's always the first two than the others I can't find a pattern.

Comment: If you copy and paste my example, do you have that error?

Comment: Please copy and paste here your input text (one example row)

Comment: Please check original post I made an edit with the information you were asking for.

Comment: @Alex I have edited my command. Is it you example input a 2 rows file? The output not is this https://gist.github.com/aborruso/6a41c79185be30a0ee276b488084a288

Comment: I am getting ```Segmentation fault (core dumped)``` when doing ```mlr --csv -N --quote-all cat then put -S 'for (k in $*){$[k]=gsub($[k],"(,|\")","")}' input.csv > output.csv```

Comment: @alex what's your Miller version? Could you put on gist the sample input?

Comment: @Alex I have edited my reply, inserting your very strange input. I don't understand now what your goal is. Can you also the output you would like?

Comment: Miller 5.6.2 and I can't put the file it's too big. There's around 42 million rows in it. I'm trying to clean the formatting in the rows and remove any ```"``` or ```,``` that are located between columns which are delimited by a ```,``` and if possible to leave the double ```"``` surrounding each string.

Comment: @Alex, I would like to help you, but I need to have something more. Extract please 100 rows and share these on gist and put here the URL

Comment: it's ok, I already coded something up in Java that took care of everything for me. I appreciate you helping so much. It's been a really valuable learning experience. I didn't even know about miller until you shared it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

in GNU awk one could use [FPAT delimiter specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html), than it would correctly handle delimiters inside quotes, but at the cost of some performance of course:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"; OFS="," } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub("\"|,","", $i)}; print $0; }' input.csv > output.csv
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"; OFS="|" } { $1=$1; print $0; }' input.csv > output2.csv
```

where FPAT regex mean

- `([^,]*)` - any string not containing `,` (delimiter) or
- `(\"[^\"]*\")` - any string between quotes `\"`, not having another quote `[^\"]` inside
- `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub("\"|,","", $i)};` - replaces `"` or `,` in field values and rebuilds record with OFS
- alternatively, use `$1=$1` is to [rebuild the record, using the current OFS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields) with delimiter `|` and then work with file as pipe-separated.

P.S. you can replace delimiter `,` with `;` or also  `*` with `+` to avoid empty field values.